# Tailwindcss doesn't work in a proper way with Nextjs + TS Project?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I use tailwindcss with next ... I was making a `BlogPost.tsx` component and it was working fine, suddenly the Styles just do not work at all, any new styles don't work in this component or anywhere else... it's been 3 days I'm looking for a solution and I can't find one I don't know what is happening

`P.S: I created a new Nextjs + TS Project and moved my files into it and the problem is still there`

I'll leave my configuration files and the component I'm working with. thanks pls help ASAP :)

`Blog.tsx`

```
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import IOArrowRight from "../icons/IOArrowRight";
import { IArticle } from "../types";
import { formatDate } from "../utils";

interface IPropType {
  article: IArticle;
}

const Blog = ({ article }: IPropType) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li className="relative flex items-baseline gap-6 pb-5">
          <div className="before:absolute before:left-[5.5px] before:h-full before:w-[.5px] before:bg-gray-400 last:hidden">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="12"
              height="12"
              className="bi bi-circle-fill fill-gray-400 mt-2"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            >
              <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" />
            </svg>
          </div>

          <div>
            <time className="mb-1 text-sm font-normal leading-none text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-500">
              {formatDate(article.attributes.createdAt)}
            </time>
            <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              {article.attributes.Title}
              <span className="bg-blue-100 text-blue-800 text-xs font-medium mr-2 px-3 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-blue-200 dark:text-blue-800 ml-3">
                Latest
              </span>
            </h3>

            <p className="mb-4 text-base font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 p-4">
              {article.attributes.shortDescription.slice(0, 250)}
              {article.attributes.shortDescription.length > 250 ? "..." : ""}
            </p>

            <div className="flex items-center my-4">
              <div className="rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center mr-2">
                {article.attributes.author.data.attributes.avatar.data
                  .attributes.formats.thumbnail.url && (
                  <Image
                    src={`http://localhost:1337${article.attributes.author.data.attributes.avatar.data.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url}`}
                    height={40}
                    width={40}
                    key={article.attributes.Slug}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
              <span className="text-sm font-bold text-gray-600 ml-4">
                {article.attributes.author.data.attributes.firstname}{" "}
                {article.attributes.author.data.attributes.lastname}{" "}
              </span>
            </div>

            <a
              href="#"
              className="inline-flex items-center justify-center py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-200 focus:text-blue-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 w-full"
            >
              Learn more <IOArrowRight className="w-4 h-4 mr-4" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

and here is my configuration files...[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you have done the following properly. Visit the [documentation page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) for more detailed explanations

1. Identify the path for your .tsx files in the config file inside on content section for pages, components and if you use src you must specify the path for src too
2. add the following codes to your global.css file

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

3. Make sure you have imported correctly the global.css file to your index.tsx file
4. Restart your server